# How are those vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I presume we can call a set of vectors a basis if it spans some subspace and are linearly independent. Is this matrix $$  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 8 & 0 & 5 \\
    0 & 11 & -3 & 5\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$ of linearly independent vectors ? Because in mine textbook it is. I'm very confused.
Can it ever be called a basis?

Comment: are your vectors the columns ? or are your vectors the rows?

Comment: these are rows.

Comment: Perhaps I should provide more information about the context?

Comment: then you only have two vectors to consider. The question of dependence versus independence for two vectors is specially simple.

Comment: Do you know the classical definition of linearly independent set, please do use the definition, it would get clear then

Comment: Why it doesn't satisfy the trivial linear combination with scalars $\lambda = 0$ ? I mean it does, but other numbers too

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/Question**:

Two vectors are linearly dependent if one of them is a scalar multiple of the other. Is this possible in the present case?

Comment: Ah, ok it's not possible because leading 0 in second vector can't ever be 1 ,multiplied by a scalar. But if I want to use the definition 
$\alpha_1X_1 + ... + \alpha_kX_k = 0$, for then $11\alpha_2 = 3\alpha_3 -5\alpha_4$ and this system of equations has a solution? I'm probably wrong here ;/

Comment: I'm not too sure of  what you have in mind with these equations? – $\alpha_1+8\alpha_2+5\alpha_4=0$ and $11\alpha_2-3\alpha_3+5\alpha_4=0$? It has solutions, for  dimensions reasons, and the set of solutions is a subspace of $\mathbf R^4$ with dimension $2$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that in the end, I know where I was wrong ,ty

Comment: Why vector $[1,0,0,0]$ spans $\Bbb{R}^4$?

Comment: It doesn't. Why do you think so?

Comment: Because it's a unit vector ,and they always form a basis.

Comment: But not a single vector is a vector space of dimension $4$. A basis is a *maximal* linearly independent family.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111584/discussion-between-user378298-and-bernard).